# sorting parts of a text file from the command line

Tags: ruby, sorting, grep

Say I have [this text file](http://pastebin.com/sshECmS4). I wanted to grab the lines that have a movie in them, match the title, print, and sort based on title. I got most of the way with:

```
File.open("features/sort_movie_list.feature","r").each {|line| puts [$1] if line =~ /\|\s+([A-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9: ]+)\s+\|/}
```

but I didn't know how to sort from there. I got some of the way with `grep`:

```
egrep -o "\|\s([A-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9: ]+)\s+\|" sort_movie_list.feature
```

but wasn't sure how to print the bracketed match only. How would you do it so that the output is as below?

```
2001: A Space Odyssey

Aladdin

Amelie

Chicken Run

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ruby example you could just stuff them into an array, sort the array and print them out.

With egrep you could pipe the results to sort:

```
egrep -o "\|\s([A-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9: ]+)\s+\|" sort_movie_list.feature | sort
```

Comment: Ah yes. I don't need to extract just the title using egrep to sort the line correctly using sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The given regexps do not catch Movie titles with comma (','), dots ('.') or other weird stuff (like german Umlauts 'ä', exclamation ("Mars Attacks!"!!)) inside.

Therefore, I would exploit the given format and assume that the pipe shall not come up in the movie title list.

Therefore, either cut the file in parts, where the pipe ("|") is the field delimiter and chose the second field, like:

```
grep "|" movies.txt | cut -f 2 -d"|" | sort
```

(The `grep "|"` is to omit lines without movies, otherwise `cut -f 2 -d "|" movies.txt` would do).

or in ruby use something along the lines

```
line.split("|")[1]
```

Note that in both cases you can get rid of whitespaces afterwards.

Comment: Looking at your input file again it might be **even better** to just take the characters within range, as the second "column" seems to be of fixed length. Like this you would even capture movies with a pipe symbol in their title.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out for Ruby now. Thanks to David for the suggesting to use an array.

```
movie_titles = []
File.open("features/sort_movie_list.feature","r").each {|line| movie_titles.push($1.strip) if line =~ /\|\s+([A-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9: ]+)\s+\|/}
puts movie_titles.sort
```

If someone has a more efficient/succinct answer, I'm always open to learning more.